# (Python) How can I get instant GPS data from Thingspeak?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps, cloud

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from urllib import request
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import threading                    # import threadding
import json                         # import json
READ_API_KEY= "ZG0YZXYKP9LOMMB9"
CHANNEL_ID= "1370649"

while True:
    TS = urllib3.urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds/last.json?api_key=%s" \
        % (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))

        response = TS.read()
        data=json.loads(response)
        
        b = data['field1']
        c = data['field2']
        print (b)
        print (c)
        time.sleep(15)
        TS.close()
```

I uploaded the data from raspberry pi to thingspeak, but in order to use it in the follium map, I need to access these data instantly. The code here seems to work but I keep getting errors. Can you help me?

Comment: while True:
    TS = urllib3.urlopen(#"http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1370649/feeds/last.json?api_key=ZG0YZXYKP9LOMMB9")

        response = TS.read()
        data=json.loads(response)
        b = data['field1']
        c = data['field2']
        print (b)
        print (c)
        time.sleep(15)
        TS.close()

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you research a bit more about [python imports](https://realpython.com/python-import/).

In the meantime, this change should fix the issue:

```
import time # you forgot to import

TS = urllib3.urlopen(#url)

   # should be 

TS = urlopen(#url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    TS = urllib3.urlopen(#"http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1370649/feeds/last.json?api_key=ZG0YZXYKP9LOMMB9")

        response = TS.read()
        data=json.loads(response)
        b = data['field1']
        c = data['field2']
        print (b)
        print (c)
        time.sleep(15)
        TS.close()

data=json.loads(response)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm searching, but I haven't found much.